# Vim: How can I search and replace on just part of each line?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I've got a list of phrases with spaces:

```
Part One
Part Two
Parts Three And Four
```

I'd like to use Vim to process the list to produce this:

```
part_one,"Part One"
part_two,"Part Two"
parts_three_and_four,"Parts Three And Four"
```

I can get use this regex:

```
:%s/.*/\L\0\E,"\0"/
```

to get me to this, which is really close:

```
part one,"Part One"
part two,"Part Two"
parts three and four,"Parts Three And Four"
```

Is there any way to replace all spaces before the comma on each with underscores? Either as a modification of the above regex or as a second command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there will never be commas in your original data, you should be able to use the following:

```
:%s/.*/\L\0\E,"\0"/ | %s/ \([^,]*,\)\@=/_/g
```

This just does another replacement after your current one to replace all of the spaces that come before a comma (using a positive lookahead).

Comment: I would have done it like this: `:%s/.*/\=substitute(tolower(submatch(0)),' ','_','g').', "'.submatch(0).'"'/`. However, I find this 2 step approach with a lookahead to be quite pleasing.

Comment: vimgolf: `:%s/.*/\L&\E,"&"/|%s/ \ze[^,]*,/_/g`

Comment: Wow, I am learning new regex tricks left & right in this answer and its comments. Didn't know about the `|`, `\@=`, or `\ze` before this. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it's very hard to google for `\@=`. For those who come after me, [here's a handy link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\@=).

Answer (score 1):

```
:g/./let @s='"'.getline('.').'"'|s/ /_/g|exec "norm! guuA,\<ESC>\"sp"
```

if I do this, I may do it with macro.

Comment: Why not just `y$` the line instead of us `getline()`? Maybe something like this: `:exe "g/./norm y$guu:s/ /_/g\<cr>A,\"\<c-r>\"\""`. Of course it can be much shorter if you use `<c-v>` to just quote the `<cr>` and `<c-r>`. Or even better lose the `:g` command and use `:norm` with a range. e.g. `%norm y$guu:s/ /_/g<c-v><cr>A,"<c-v><c-r>""`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an expression in the replacement part, like:

```
:%s/\v^.*$/\=tolower(substitute(submatch(0), "\\s\\+", "_", "g")) . ",\"" . submatch(0) . "\""/
```

It first substitute all whitespaces with `_`, and the returned string is lowercased. Then it joins the result with the matched line surrounded with double quotes.

It yields:

```
part_one,"Part One"
part_two,"Part Two"
parts_three_and_four,"Parts Three And Four"
```

Comment: Why `\v^.*$` when `.*` works just as well?  If you use literal strings, then you do not need to double all those backslashes:  `'\s\+'` is the same as `"\\s\\+"`.

Answer (score 0):

From where you left off, I would split all the lines after the comma:

```
:%s/,/,\r/
```

Then you can replace the spaces on just the lines with a comma and join your lines back together:

```
:g/,/:s/ /_/g|j!
```

Comment: Forget joining w/ a substitution use `:join`. So `:g/,/s/ /_/g|j!` instead.

Comment: I did it this way to be super precise, because @abeger didn't include a space after the comma in the requested format. That's good feedback, though.

Comment: Never mind, I see that that's what the j! does now. I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as second command:

```
:%s/\(\(,.*\)\@<=\)\@! /_/g
```

`\(\(,.*\)\@<=\)\@!` inversely match `,"Part One"`, `,"Part Two"` ...

Also:

```
:%s/ \(.*"..*\)\@=/_/g
```